# How to count large numbers of pushpins in Bing Maps?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm designing a Map for the networking problems in my country and I have 1000 or more points per city. When I see the city without Zoom I'd like to show the full count (for example 50) of the points in that place and if you use the zoom start to showing the new pushpins with the new number for example 10 in somewhere and other 15 in another place.

How can I do it? If is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do Clustering on Pushpins: [Pushpin Clustering on V7 interactive SDK](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#LoadingDynamicModule1)